# Expectation of the number balls are drawn

Tags: expectation, hypergeometric-function

A box contains 6 white balls and 4 black balls. Balls are drawn from the box without replacement until either a white ball is drawn or 3 balls have been drawn. Find the expected number of balls that will be drawn from the box.

Comment: The random variable $X$ that gives the number of balls drawn takes on values $1,2,3$. Calculate $\Pr(X=1)$ (W), $\Pr(X=2)$ (BW). Then we know $\Pr(X=3)$ and now we know everything.  For a full answer, I suggest that next time you indicate what you have tried.

Comment: E(x) = (6 choose x)(4 choose choose 3-x)/(10 3) where x=0,1,2,3 but this is wrong! @AndréNicolas

Comment: $\Pr(X=1)=\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}=p_1$; $\Pr(X=2)=\frac{4}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9}=\frac{4}{15}=p_2$; so $\Pr(X=3)=1-p_1-p_2=\frac{1}{3}=p_3$. Expectation is $(1)(p_1)+(2)(p_2)+(3)(p_3)$.

Comment: The distribution is not hypergeometric, so using the hypergeometric distribution function is not right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  If only one ball is drawn, it must be white.  The probability that this happens is
$$p_1=\frac6{10}\ .$$
If two balls are drawn they must be... then... so the probability is
$$p_2=\cdots\ .$$
See if you can fill in the gaps, then find the probability that $3$ balls are drawn, $4$ balls etc.  Then the expectation is
$$1p_1+2p_2+\cdots\ .$$
Good luck!